# php function inside twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a twig template in which i render some information taking from the database. The length of the information is quite large and it does not fit in the space provided for it. I want to use **substr** function of php inside my twig template.

The index.html.twig contains

```
 <span>{{ patent.description }}</span>
```

The description is very long I want to display the first 80 characters of the whole description.

In php I can use

```
 substr(patent.description,0,80)
```

Can anyone guide me how i can use this function inside my twig template?

Comment: you can do it before passing it to the template. maybe in your controller

Comment: I have multiple entries and for each entry i take its name and description. from controller I pass just patents and then in my template i use foreach patent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slice function does this,

```
<span>{{ patent.description|slice(0,80) }}</span>
```

The slice filter works as the array_slice PHP function for arrays and substr for strings.
It was added in Twig 1.6.

Comment: After that you can add ...  And of course some if statement for case when description is empty. Did the same work today =)